# Socket Server with netty-socketio and Piesocket tester

Tags: socket.io, netty-socketio

I am using [netty-socketio](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio) to create a server on Android and using [PieSocket](https://www.piesocket.com/socketio-tester?v=3) to test connecting the server.But I get the error on PieSocket as below:

[image]

> Ensure preflight responses are valid
> A cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) request was blocked because the response to the associated preflight request failed, had an unsuccessful HTTP status code, and/or was a redirect.
> To fix this issue, ensure all CORS preflight OPTIONS requests are answered with a successful HTTP status code (2xx) and do not redirect.

On the server, I have the connection from PieSocket, which means PieSocket has connected to the server. So how netty-socketio server treating this connection, like sending back any events or something else?

My Server Configs:

```
        private val socketServer: SocketIOServer by lazy {
        SocketIOServer(Configuration().apply {
            hostname = mHost
            port = mPort
            isAllowCustomRequests = true
        })
    }
```

Btw, I have used [socket.io-client-java](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java) to test on an Android device, and it was successful.